# Spectrograms generated using Librosa don't look consistent with Kaldi?

Tags: speech-recognition, spectrogram, mfcc, librosa, kaldi

I generated spectrogram of a "seven" utterance using the "egs/tidigits" code from Kaldi, using 23 bins, 20kHz sampling rate, 25ms window, and 10ms shift. Spectrogram appears as below visualized via MATLAB imagesc function:

[image: kaldi "seven" spectrogram]

I am experimenting with using Librosa as an alternative to Kaldi. I set up my code as below using the same number of bins, sampling rate, and window length / shift as above.

```
time_series, sample_rate = librosa.core.load("7a.wav",sr=20000)
spectrogram = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(time_series, sr=20000, n_mels=23, n_fft=500, hop_length=200)
log_S = librosa.core.logamplitude(spectrogram)
np.savetxt("7a.txt", log_S.T)
```

However when I visualize the resulting Librosa spectrogram of the same WAV file it looks different:

[image: librosa "seven" spectrogram]

Can someone please help me understand why these look so different? Across other WAV files I've tried I notice that with my Librosa script above, my fricatives (like the /s/ in "seven" in the above example) are being cutoff and this is greatly affecting my digit classification accuracy. Thank you!

Comment: This question belongs to http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kaldi applies lifter by default on dct output, thats why upper coefficients are attenuated. See details [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26019/sinusoidal-liftering-in-implementations-of-mfcc).

Comment: I see, yes I'm familiar with the concept of liftering. Do you know if there's a way to apply liftering to my script in Librosa as well? I also came across this library (http://python-speech-features.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which seems to have more common ASR options

Comment: It should be a standard multiplication on a vector. You can precompute vector before extracting features.